# how do i fit unique curves on each unique plot in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, curve-fitting

I have written this code (see below) for my data frame `kleaf.df` to combine multiple plots of variable `press_mV` with each individual plot for unique `ID`

I need some help fitting curves to my plots. when i run this code i get the same fitted curve (the curve fitted for the first plot) on ALL the plots  where i want each unique fitted curve on each unique plot.

thanks in advance for any help given

```
f <- function(t,a,b) {a * exp(b * t)}    
par(mfrow = c(5, 8), mar = c(1,1,1,1), srt = 0, oma = c(1,6,5,1))
for (i in unique(kleaf.df$ID))
{
d <- subset(kleaf.df, kleaf.df$ID == i)
plot(c(1:length(d$press_mV)),d$press_mV)
#----tp:turning point. the last maximum value before the values start to decrease
tp <- tail(which( d$press_mV == max(d$press_mV) ),1)
#----set the end points(A,B) to fit the curve to
A <- tp+5
B <- A+20
#----t = time, p = press_mV 
#     n.b:shift by 5 accomadate for the time before attachment
t <- A:B+5
p <- d$press_mV[A:B]
fit <- nls(p ~ f(t,a,b), start = c(a=d$press_mV[A], b=-0.01))
#----draw a curve on plot using the above coefficents
curve(f(x, a=co[1], b=co[2]), add = TRUE, col="green", lwd=2)
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code that "runs". All I see is a function definition (and it appears there is a call to the same function, `f`, within the definition.)

Comment: sorry BondedDust I'm pretty new to all this so my understanding of the lingo isn't up to scratch. what do you mean  by not seeing any code that "runs" ? everything i have in my Rscript is here (with exception of loading the csv file as kleaf.df)

Comment: i think i get what your saying BondedDust but the function definition ends on the first line after that I've set the parameters for the multi plot, then i go in for the 'for' loop which i use the function in. cheers

Comment: No. It doesn't "end" until the closing curley-brace appears ... at the very end of the currently posted code. Moral: start using a syntax-aware editor.